# Why doesnt lua_newlib work in this example?

Tags: c, lua

I tried to call from a lua script the c method my_sin. I'm using lua 5.2.2 and wanted to test to use luaL_newlib instead of lua_register. Unfortunately, the lua script doesn't find mysin.

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
}

#include <cmath>

static int my_sin (lua_State *L) {
  lua_pushnumber(L, sin(luaL_checknumber(L, 1)));
  return 1;
}
static const luaL_Reg my_lib[] = {
   {"mysin",   my_sin},
   {NULL, NULL}
};

int my_open(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_newlib(L, my_lib);  
  return 1;
}

int main() {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L); 
    my_open(L);
    luaL_dostring(L, "print(mysin(2))");
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably, you should add `lua_setglobal(L, "mylib");` just after `luaL_newlib()` and call your function using its full name `mylib.mysin(2)`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, in this case, `my_open` should return 0.

Comment: @lhf - What's the meaning of the value returned by `my_open`?  Why not `void my_open()`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, it could be void in this example but if the library is meant to be required then you need the open function to follow the usual Lua C protocol.

Comment: @lhf - In that case, `my_open` must be renamed to `luaopen_mylib`, isn't it?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

luaL_newlib creates a new table and populates it from a list of functions. Your function mysin is inside this table and is not a global function. If you want it to be a global function, use lua_register.